# SQL - Checking special characters in email

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to verify whether the email is valid. I have tried the below query,

```
--if the email is valid,
WHERE (CHARINDEX('',LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)))=0  
                    AND LEFT(LTRIM(Email),1)<> '@' 
                    AND RIGHT(RTRIM(Email),1)<> '.'
                    AND CHARINDEX('.',Email, CHARINDEX('@',Email))-CHARINDEX('@',Email)>1
                    AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)))-LEN(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Email)),'@',''))=1
                    AND CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(Email))))>=3
                    AND(CHARINDEX('.@',Email)=0 AND CHARINDEX('..',Email)=0)) AND @Email LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

but if i type in the special letters like '#,$*()!%^&{}[]' such as as#$fe@df.com, it will not detect the special characters in the email. Can someone please help me with this? I also need to allow only underscore and dash in the email, like er_ds@op-a.com

Thank you

Comment: Not quite a job for SQL. It's much easier to do it in your client code (and if it's a scripting language maybe it even provides a validation function for email addresses.)

Comment: `AND Email LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9]'` well, you are telling it that you only want letters and numbers.

Comment: Actually, if you wanted to exclude non-legal characters, you would have to use a NOT LIKE construct.

Comment: @Stephen the problem is this statement is not working. if there are any other special characters, it still says the email is valid

Comment: @LaughingVergil i tried but it still doesnt work. `not like '%[*&^%$#()]%'` like that?

Comment: In this case, it is easier to use a double negative. This - `NOT (@e like '%[^-A-Za-z0-9_@.]%')` - is the preferred pattern. The caret in the front of the set says "Match anything not in this set". You then list all valid characters in the set and, if anything in the email matches, you have an invalid character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one compare that handles most of your currently specified test cases much more simply, implemented as a stored procedure for testing purposes:

```
Use TempDB
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE xspValidate(@e varchar(128))
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN @e like '_%_@_%.__%'
        AND NOT (
            @e like '%[^-A-Za-z0-9_@.]%'
            OR @e like '%[.@][.@]%'
            OR @e LIKE '%@%@%'
            )
            THEN 'Valid'
        ELSE 'Wrong'
    END
END

GO


EXEC xspValidate 'bob@ray.com'  -- valid
EXEC xspValidate 'bob@q.com'    -- valid
EXEC xspValidate 'b*b@ray.com'  -- wrong
EXEC xspValidate 'A@b.C'        -- wrong
EXEC xspValidate 'Alpha@@numeric.com'   -- wrong
EXEC xspValidate 'Alpha@.com'   -- wrong
```

Comment: Note that this excludes tons of valid emails based on the RFC requirements for email addresses, such as the requirement that anything can go between double quotes. This - `Alb"@*$&%(j VB"ert@ray.com` - is a legal email address according to the full specification. But no one handles these addresses as far as I know.

Comment: but google only accept numbers, letters and period tho.

Comment: i think `NOT (@e like '%[^-A-Za-z0-9_@.]%')` works for me. thank you